# Requests not being sent when testing gRPC asyncio bidirectional streaming

Tags: python, python-asyncio, grpc

Using Python `3.10` and

```
grpcio         1.49.1  HTTP/2-based RPC framework
grpcio-tools   1.49.1  Protobuf code generator for gRPC
```

I'm trying to get the following example to work against a service we have.  The RPC I'm calling represents a bidirectional stream.  I'm using a queue to provide the requests that should be streamed, but I never see the requests go across the wire.

Here is the sample code:

```
import asyncio
import logging
import queue
import threading
import time

# noinspection PyPackageRequirements
import grpc.aio

from coherence.services_pb2_grpc import NamedCacheServiceStub
from coherence.utils import JSONSerializer, RequestFactory

new_loop = asyncio.new_event_loop()
new_loop.set_debug(True)
sentinel = "poison"


def run_loop(loop):
    asyncio.set_event_loop(loop)
    loop.run_forever()


async def run_queue(client_stub, send_queue):
    print("START LOOP")

    stream = client_stub.events(iter(send_queue.get, sentinel))  # initiate bidirectional streaming
    async for entry_response in stream:
        print(f"RESPONSE: {entry_response}")

    print("DONE LOOP")  # shouldn't be printed; queue should block if no items


def start_stream_handler(client_stub, send_queue):
    threading.Thread(target=lambda: run_loop(new_loop), daemon=True).start()
    asyncio.run_coroutine_threadsafe(run_queue(client_stub, send_queue), new_loop)


async def events_basic():
    channel = grpc.aio.insecure_channel("127.0.0.1:1408")
    send_queue = queue.Queue()

    cache_name = "foo"
    serializer = JSONSerializer()
    client_stub = NamedCacheServiceStub(channel)
    request_factory = RequestFactory(cache_name, "", serializer)

    start_stream_handler(client_stub, send_queue)
    time.sleep(5.0)

    print("Feeding the queue ...")
    send_queue.put_nowait(request_factory.map_event_subscribe())

    print("Giving time to drain request queue ...")

    time.sleep(5.0)
    print(f"Expected queue size is [0]; actual: [{send_queue.qsize()}]")
    print("EXIT")

if __name__ == '__main__':
    logging.basicConfig(level=logging.DEBUG)
    asyncio.run(events_basic())
```

When running the above, the following is output:

```
DEBUG:asyncio:Using selector: KqueueSelector
DEBUG:grpc._cython.cygrpc:Using AsyncIOEngine.POLLER as I/O engine
START LOOP
Feeding the queue ...
Giving time to drain request queue ...
Expected queue size is [0]; actual: [1]
EXIT
DEBUG:grpc.aio._call:Client request_iterator raised exception:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/rlubke/Library/Caches/pypoetry/virtualenvs/coherence-NZNGCFtv-py3.10/lib/python3.10/site-packages/grpc/aio/_call.py", line 417, in _consume_request_iterator
    await self._write(request)
  File "/Users/rlubke/Library/Caches/pypoetry/virtualenvs/coherence-NZNGCFtv-py3.10/lib/python3.10/site-packages/grpc/aio/_call.py", line 439, in _write
    await self._metadata_sent.wait()
  File "/Users/rlubke/.pyenv/versions/3.10.1/lib/python3.10/asyncio/locks.py", line 213, in wait
    await fut
asyncio.exceptions.CancelledError
```

When watching Wireshark while this runs, I never see any network activity on port `1408`.

Thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

Answer is best to not share gRPC artifacts between event loops.